# Изображение не сохраняется функцией imwrite, OpenCV

Tags: python, telebot, opencv

Я написал чат бота для телеграмма, который принимает изображение, отправленное ему и находит на нем лица, а затем на полученные координаты наносит блюр. Но почему то данное изображение не сохраняется командой `imwrite`. В боте нет, как я понял, ошибок, telebot покойно принимает изображение из телеграмма, и сохраняет его. Как сделать так, чтобы изображение сохранилось?

```
import time

from telebot import TeleBot
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
import cv2
import os

bot = TeleBot(token='токен')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def hello(message):

    button_base = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    btn1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Продолжить', callback_data='cont')
    btn2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Выход', callback_data='exit')
    button_base.add(btn1, btn2)

    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text=f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}! Отрпавь мне изобрважение', reply_markup=button_base)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback(call):
    if call.data == 'cont':
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text=f'Прекрасно! Отрпавь мне изображение!')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def photo(message):

    ID = message.photo[-1].file_id
    file_info = bot.get_file(ID)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

    with open('image5.jpg', 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
        img = cv2.imread('image5.jpg')
        cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalcatface_extended.xml')
        

        res = cascade.detectMultiScale(image=img,
                                           scaleFactor=1.2,
                                           minNeighbors=5,

                                           )
        for (x, y, w, h) in res:
            face_img = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            blurred_face = cv2.GaussianBlur(face_img, (23, 23), 10)
            img[y:y + h, x:x + w] = blurred_face

            cv2.imwrite(f'blur.png', img)
            time.sleep(20)
            bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=open('blur.png', 'rb'))


bot.polling(non_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: может быть, оно сохраняет, только не туда, куда вы ожидаете?

Comment: нет, я смотрел оно вообще не сохраняется

Comment: Эта строка у меня возвращает пустой кортеж: `res = cascade.detectMultiScale(image=img, scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=5)`, а поскольку как сохранение так и отправка изображения находятся в теле цикла(что в корне не верно), то программа просто не обрабатывает данный кусок кода. И да я пробовал разные изображения.